# it seems that i am getting error requests.exceptions.ConnectionError getaddrinfo failed because a minus

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using requests to send post request with the following code:

```
EMAIL=test@test.com
payload  = {'ref':'EdX7CqkmjCETTSA9MOPvvmmhLE0OH9_D-zjde6lAKsOoKD8','EMAIL':EMAIL,'tag': 'F41D3B010005FB43'}
post_response = requests.post(url='http://p5trc.emv2.com/D2TTF8', params=payload)
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 1090, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\POST_ME.py", line 72, in <module>
    post_response = requests.post(url='http://p5trc.emv2.com/D2TTF8', params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\api.py", line 98, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\safe_mode.py", line 39, in wrapped
    return function(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\api.py", line 51, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\sessions.py", line 268, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\models.py", line 650, in send
    self._build_response(r)
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\models.py", line 313, in _build_response
    request.send()
  File "C:\Users\USER\workspace\POST_ME\requests\models.py", line 636, in send
    raise ConnectionError(sockerr)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

When removing the minus character from string `EdX7CqkmjCETTSA9MOPvvmmhLE0OH9_D-zjde6lAKsOoKD8` or removing `'tag': 'F41D3B010005FB43'`  from the dictionary I don't get the exception.

Any Idea?

Comment: what do you see with `nslookup p5trc.emv2.com`?

Answer (score 0):

The exception was raised after several attempts to call `getaddrinfo`, which is used to translate the hostname (`p5trc.emv2.com`) into a network address. You must have had some network problems, your DNS server was temporarily not reachable.

The fact that it then worked when you changed your script has *nothing* to do with that error. Your DNS server became reachable again.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your answer but it doesn't seems likely. this url is a high availability  url and I am sure i dont have a network problem. More then that I have tested the code with the two requests. one after each other and one worked and the other raised an exception.

Comment: HI can you think about something else. it seems that the same url works through browser